# How to choose working database in DB2?

Tags: sql-server, db2

In SQL server I can use the `USE` [statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx) to switch between working databases. Is there a similar command for DB2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept of a "database" in SQL Server is much closer to a schema in DB2.  An entire MS SQL database engine is much closer to a DB2 database:

```
master database <======> SYSIBM/SYSCAT schema
msdb   database <======> SYSPROC       schema
```

It's not a perfect comparison; there are a number of differences:

- DB2 does not have an equivalent to the `model` database.
- `tempdb` doesn't really map to a schema; its purpose is handled by system temporary tablespace(s) like `TEMPSPACE1`.
- Each database in MS SQL has separate log files, where DB2 uses a single set of transaction logs for the entire database

---

Therefore, technically the closest equivalent to MS SQL's `USE` statement is `SET SCHEMA`.  Issuing the `SET SCHEMA x` statement tells DB2 where to look for unqualified objects.

However, it's not a requirement to issue the `SET SCHEMA` statement if you fully qualify your object names.  The following statements:

```
set schema x;
select c1, c2 from mytable;
```

are equivalent to:

```
select c1, c2 from x.mytable
```

Using `set schema` simply allows you to use unqualified objects.